# Is there a valid word for 'exclusatory'?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367075/8611102), I wrote:

> Now, there is zero evidence that someone who feels marginalized was made to feel marginalized due to racism or sexism or ableism or any other exclusatory ism.

Rereading the post, I noticed that exclusatory, though fully understandable, isn't technically a 'real' word (in the sense of being included in dictionaries.)

Is there a valid subsitute with a similar meaning?

Comment: 'exclusionary'. A thesaurus might give you other suggestions

Comment: I posted an answer.  Word of advice, lose the "Now," from the beginning of the sentence if you're meaning to be formal.

Comment: Although *excuse* can become *excusatory*, there is no derivational path from *exclude* to *exclusatory*.

Comment: Yes, of course, exclusion, exclusionary. or exclusionist.

Answer (score 2):

I would have used "exclusive" or "exclusionary." "Exclusionism" merely means "the character, manner, or principles of an exclusionist; exclusivism." An "exclusionism" isn't a word denoting exclusion...

Answer (score 1):

The word you are actually looking for is [exclusionism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exclusionism?s=t).  You could say "exclusionary ism" instead, but there's a word for that: "exclusionism."

Example:

"...due to racism or sexism or ableism or any other exclusionism."

Comment: _Exclusionism_ is not necessarily the same as an exclusionary ism. Exclusionism is (also) a particular kind of ism. It’s a [Wikipedia philosophy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Exclusionism), for example, and in political terms it’s the practice of excluding certain groups from society and/or rights. An ism that happens to be exclusionary in nature (such as racism or sexism) doesn’t normally entail excluding the target from society or their rights.

Comment: Yes, words have multiple meanings, so any word I put up is going to "not necessarily be the same" because of those multiple definitions.  However, there is a definition--the main definition, in fact, as in the first on listed--where "exclusionism" specifically means "exclusionary ism."

Comment: Most isms aren't words but doctrines or practices.

Answer (score 1):

I might go with

- [exclusionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exclusionary)

> There is zero evidence that someone who feels marginalized was made to feel marginalized due to racism or sexism or ableism or any other *exclusionary* practices.

Better to use it as a modifier to your meaning is crystal clear.

- [exclusionism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusionism?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

> There is zero evidence that someone who feels marginalized was made to feel marginalized due to racism or sexism or ableism or any other forms of exclusionism.

*Posting this partly because I think it's wildly inaccurate that "exclusionism" doesn't carry this meaning, as suggested by other answers.*

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=+exclusatory+&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch), when presented with ***exclusatory***, says:

> No dictionary entries found for ‘ exclusatory ’.
>
> Did you mean:
>
> •excusatory •exclamatory ***•exclusory*** •excusator •accusatory  (Emphasis added)

Clicking on **exclusory**, I find the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65839?redirectedFrom=exclusory#eid) says:

> Having the power or the function of excluding; tending to exclude

**Exclusory** would work in the OP's sentence, although I admit to wondering why exclusatory is not a word when exclamatory, excusatory and accusatory are.  But that is a different question.